# How to configure Thorntail http port with project-default.yml?

Tags: thorntail

I'm using Thorntail 2.3.0.Final, in documentation "5.4.2. Sockets" there is an example of configuring some kind of something:

```
 thorntail:
   network:
     socket-binding-groups:
       standard-sockets:
         http:
           port: 8081
```

I thought it starts listening on port 8081, but it persistently continues start listening port 8080

so how to configure port binding properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortcut way is to use:

```
thorntail:
  http:
    port: 8081
```